# Equation with absolute values (another)

Tags: roots

How many roots (finite number) can equation have?
$$ \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{40}|a_i - x| = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{40}|b_i - x|.$$
I think there is at most one, but I don't know how to prove it. Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help if you edit the question to show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Can you answer the question when you change $40$ to $1$ or $2$?

Comment: Are there any restrictions on $a_i$ and $b_i$?

Comment: @CYAries, no, any real numbers

Comment: Technically, if you take $a_i=b_i$ then you have infinitely many solutions

Comment: @asdf  I fixed the question.

Comment: @EthanBolker, I'll take that, thank you

Comment: $|x-2|+|x-3|=|x-1|+|x-0|$ has only one solution. But $|x-2|+|x-(-1)|=|x-1|+|x-0|$ has infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @CYAries, the question is how many roots can equation have if the number of roots is finite number

Comment: @Konstant:  It would improve the Question if you added this condition to the body text in a more robust way, e.g. assume that the following equation has a finite number of roots....  It would also help to show Readers you've digested the problem to illustrate one or more cases where there are infinitely many roots.

Comment: $|1-x|+|5-x|+|6-x|=|2-x|+|2-x|+|9-x| $ has $3$ roots

Answer (score 1):

If $\sum_{i=1}^{40}a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{40}b_i$ for large enough $x$ we have $$\sum_{i=1}^{40}x-a_i=\sum_{i=1}^{40}x-b_i\to0=0$$which means that under such assumption we can have infinitely many answers. Generally the number of answers depends on the values of $\{a_i\}$ and $\{b_i\}$ and has no closed form.

Comment: OP proposed that the equation either has infinitely many solutions or has not more than one solution. Can anybody give a counter-example?

Comment: $|1-x|+|5-x|+|6-x|=|2-x|+|2-x|+|9-x|$ has $3$ roots